# how to remove identical data in field

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel file of 6 colums and more than 2000 rows. Data in Colum B is identical to E and C is identical to F.
However, data in a cell of col B can match with in cell of col E. Further, the matched colums may have special characters.
Please anybody help me to identify and sort the matching onse?

Comment: Please clarify your question so we can reproduce the problem, instead of trying to guess at what you mean.  See the HELP topics for [how to ask a good question](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) for further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Please specify what you want exactly, removing the identical cells in Column B & E or just identify and sort ?

If you want to identify you can use conditional formatting:

Highlight Column B & E, and then go to Home > Under 'Styles' Section Conditional Formatting > Highlight Cell Rules > Identical Values > Duplicate Values with *formatting you want eg. highlight colours / fonts* (Default will be Light Red highlight fill with Dark Red Text).

and then you can sort/filter accordingly.

If you want to remove identical cells in both columns, just highlight both columns, go to Data tab > under 'Data tools' section > click 'Remove Duplicates'.

Hope that helps.